# Application not installing on BlackBerry simulator

Tags: blackberry

I am developing an application for BlackBerry. When I run the application in the simulator, it shows a message that the workspace encountered a problem:

> Error: Cannot run program "jar":
>   CreateProcess error=2, The system
>   cannot find the file specified
>   Packaging project REL-1.1.1 failed
>   (took 3.773 seconds)

What should i do next?

Comment: which problem workspace encounters ?

Comment: Error: Cannot run program "jar": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
Packaging project REL-1.1.1 failed (took 3.773 seconds)

Comment: can you add the complete error and code where you get it in your question?

Comment: Make sure your JRE is setup correct: http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800738/800901/Support_-_I_O_Error_CreateProcess.html?nodeid=800760&vernum=0  

Did you install the BB Eclipse plug-in into an existing Eclipse install or as a standalone install?   ALso, make sure your application name just has alphaNums (Just for testing that your name does't have an illegal char in it).

Answer (score 0):

Copy the jar file.

```
from:     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\jar.exe 
to:       C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\jar.exe
```

And, restart your eclipse.